# Counting average length of list of lists

Tags: python, list

I wish I could get the average length of each element in this list

I've tried the above:

```
lista=[("a,b,c"),1,1,2,(1,"n")]

for i in lista:
    a=[]
    a.append(i)
    print(len(a))
```

The actual result is len=1 for each element. I guess I couldnt get inside the lists elements... The expected result would be: 3,1,1,1,2

Comment: `("a,b,c")` is a string between parentheses. Your question has a typo probably

Answer (score 1):

Simply try to retrive the len and capture the error if not:

```
lista=[("a,b,c"),1,1,2,(1,"n")]

for i in lista:
    try:
        print(len(i))
    except TypeError:
        print(1)
```

Comment: nitpick: "Simply check if it can be iterated": that's not what `len` does.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`iter`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/iter) function to check if an element is iterable and if it is, then get its length, else append `1`:

```
lista=[("a,b,c"),1,1,2,(1,"n")]

for elem in lista:
    try:
        iter(elem)
        print(len(elem))
    except TypeError:
        print(1)
```

Result:

```
5
1
1
1
2
```

The reason that the first element is a `5` and not a `3` is because the first element of `lista` is a tuple containing only one string. Could be a typo.

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is you're not checking the length of your list but of the newly created list a[i] which is of length one by design
You want:

```
lista=[("a,b,c"),1,1,2,(1,"n")]

lengths=[]
for i in lista:
    if isinstance(i,int):
        lengths.append(1)
    else:
        try:
            lengths.append(len(i))
        except:
            pass
print lengths
```

Edit :My previous version was indeed not working

Comment: @Jean-François Fabre: I edited my answer accordingly

Comment: still no go. `list(1)` doesn't work. Test your answer, you'll see.